# Is it possible to calculate logarithms mechanically (other than with a slide rule)?

Tags: logarithms, math-history

I know that mechanical computers have been used for a number of different calculations, the most famous (at least on the [internet](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2020/05/gears-of-war-when-mechanical-analog-computers-ruled-the-waves/)) seems to be the firing control computer used by the US Navy. But were there any entirely mechanical devices (other than a slide rule) that could calculate logarithms?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by calculate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_engine#Design

Comment: In principle, anything a computer can do could be done by a mechanical machine. Indeed, computers are just mechanical machines, but with electrons as their moving parts. Logarithms aren't magic; there are specific algorithms for computation (i.e. compute up to whatever precision we want) that we could do by hand, or that a machine could do mechanically. Whether someone has actually constructed a machine, I don't know, but is it possible? Certainly.

Comment: Values of logarithm functions ("base-10", then, much later, "natural logarithm") have very early be computed (by hand, painfully) with **many** decimals (10 decimals in the tables of Adriaan Vlacq in 1628 !). Mechanical devices for computing functions have never achieved a capacity of giving more than a few decimals (3 or 4)

Comment: I added the tag math-history, but you can probably crosspost to hsm (https://hsm.stackexchange.com/), there are there specialized people tha tmay know that kind of stuff.

Comment: Newton calculated logarithms by hand to 50 decimal places, so there are methods to do so, they're just really time-intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Konrad Zuse developed the relais driven computer in 1942 in Berlin.

[K. Zuse Z4 Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z4_(computer))

I got my qualification as an ALGOL programmer at U. Würzburg on a Zuse Z22 with electronic tubes in 1962.

[K. Zuse Z22 Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z22_(computer))

Comment: Interesting testimony but not directly answering the question...

Comment: In the times of the Z4, besides office mathematicians,  mostly physicists used the Walther or something similar. http://public.beuth-hochschule.de/hamann/walther/w-160/index.html.  For Log approximations its enough to know Log 2 and Log 10 even with pencil and paper..

Comment: I didn't know this brand mark. I knew a similar one by Olivetti. Indeed, values of logarithms weren't the object of calculation by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The first was probably [the Scheutz Difference Engine](https://americanhistory.si.edu/collections/search/object/nmah_997042) of 1855, who was inspired by Charles Babbage's uncompleted Difference Engine. There's also one by [Martin Wiberg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kF3eIVmu3zQ) a decade or two later. You can read about a much later successful one on the [Computer Timeline](http://www.computer-timeline.com/timeline/christel-hamann/) site:

> The Differential Engine of Christel Hamann
>
> In 1905 The Royal Prussian Academy of Sciences in Berlin placed a considerable sum (15000 Marks, later on Imperial Academy of Sciences in Vienna granted additional 8000 Krones) at the disposal of German professors Julius Bauschinger (Director of the Imperial Observatory of Strasbourg) and Johann Peters (assistant of the Royal Astronomical Calculating Institute of Berlin), in order to prepare and publish tables of logarithms to eight digital places of all numbers from 1 to 200000.
>
> The work started using hand calculations in 1908, but the progress was so slow, that in the same year Bauschinger and Peters contacted Christel Hamann and asked him to put his long experience at his disposal and to construct a new machine, by means of which the values were to be reckoned from the second differences by summation and at once written down.
>
> Hamann readily accepted the challenge. Only several months were enough for the genius-constructor, and the machine (see the nearby photo) was ready at the beginning of 1909. It immediately went into action, worked perfectly, and surpassed all expectations.

There were probably some others, but not very many since they are essentially very expensive single use machines. It is much more profitable to sell the logarithm tables they produce, or to construct a general mechanical calculator that can be sold many times.